# Is it possible to make own select list with values in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, controller

I've got a question. Is it possible to make in asp.net core own select list with values like 8:00, 8:15, 8:30 etc.
I made list in razor view something like that bellow

```
@{
                    string iString = "";
                    string mString = "";
                }
                @for (int i = 8; i < 18; i++)
                {
                    if (i < 10)
                    {
                        iString = "0" + i;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        iString = i.ToString();
                    }
                    int m = 0;
                    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                    {
                        if (m < 10)
                        {
                            mString = "0" + m;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mString = m.ToString();
                        }
                        if (i == 10 && j == 2)
                        {
                            <option value="@iString:@mString" disabled class="text-danger">@iString:@mString</option>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <option value="@iString:@mString">@iString:@mString</option>
                        }
                        m += 15;
                    }
                }
```

And I want to make the same but in controller because I need to disable some of this options (I think this is possible to make in SelectList in controller to disable this) Any ideas any advice? Maybe is other way to create somethink like that.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a demo based on your codes, you can refer to it:

**Controller:**

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    List<SelectListItem> selectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    string iString = "";
    string mString = "";
    for (int i = 8; i < 18; i++)
    {
        if (i < 10)
        {
            iString = "0" + i;
        }
        else
        {
            iString = i.ToString();
        }
        int m = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            SelectListItem selectListItem = new SelectListItem();
            if (m < 10)
            {
                mString = "0" + m;
            }
            else
            {
                mString = m.ToString();
            }
            if (i == 10 && j == 2)
            {
                selectListItem.Disabled = true;
            }
            selectListItem.Text = iString + ":" + mString;
            selectListItem.Value = iString + ":" + mString;
            selectListItems.Add(selectListItem);
            m += 15;
        }
    }
    ViewBag.selectlist = selectListItems;
    return View();
}
```

**View:**

```
<select asp-items="@ViewBag.selectlist">

</select>
```

**Result:**

[image]